# overwrite_params deprecated as of Rails 2.3.6 -- Accepted Workaround?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, deprecated

So, it looks like `overwrite_params` is deprecated as of Rails 2.3.6.  Is there a suitable workaround that is generally accepted as best-practice?

For example, I used to to be able to do the following (which I thought was quite useful):

```
url_for(:overwrite_params => {:page => 1})
```

I've seen the following solution mentioned online ... is this the new way to do it?

```
url_for(request.params.merge(:page => 1))
```

Thanks for the help.

Comment: never actually seen overwrite_params before ... always just pass in what I need for the url helper method. Interesting.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I actually just saw this mentioned in a Railscast episode: http://railscasts.com/episodes/240-search-sort-paginate-with-ajax

He suggests basically what you said, using params.merge.  Note that you don't need to say request.params, params is sufficient.  Also if you're using link_to, then you may not need url_for.  In other words, if you have:

```
link_to title, url_for(params.merge(:page => 1))
```

then it might suffice to say

```
link_to title, params.merge(:page => 1)
```